# crop div background image to the middle when resizing the div (its responsive the div)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is a Codepen with the problem I have:

http://codepen.io/rasmus/pen/pvXjOG

html:

```
<div></div>
```

css:

```
div {
  background: url("http://placehold.it/600x300");
  background-size: cover;
  max-width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

When I'm now resizing the div - because my viewport is narrower than 600px e.g. - the background image is "cropped" to the left side. But I want to have it "cropped" on both sides, so that I can still see the middle of the picture.

What's my mistake? I know it can be done. An Example would be http://comfortzonecrusher.com e.g.

Comment: use `background-position: center;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use this:

```
background-position: center;
```

So your CSS becomes:

```
div {
  background: url("http://placehold.it/600x300");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  max-width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

Updated Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xbowmZ

Answer (score 1):

Try `background-size: contain;` on your div.